# updating the parent document when inserting sub-sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-schema, mongoose-schema, subdocument

I have a list which can have some items, those items can have sub-items and those sub items can have their sub items so on.. Iam able to insert a new item and its sub item and update the list of those changes, but when trying to insert sub-item of the sub-item, my list does not gets updated.
here is my function of inserting sub-item

```
   let addSubItems = (req, res) => {
if (check.isEmpty(req.params.itemId)) {
    console.log("error:item id not found")
    let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'no itemId found', 403, null)
    res.send(apiResponse)
} else {
    ItemModel.findOne({ "itemId": req.params.itemId }).exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'err occured in item find', 403, null)
            res.send(apiResponse)
        }else if(check.isEmpty(result)){
            console.log("no item matched")
            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'no item found', 403, null)
            res.send(apiResponse)
        } 
        else {

            console.log("this is the item inside which subitem is to be added")
            console.log(result)
            let newItem = new ItemModel({
                itemId: shortid.generate(),
                itemTitle: req.body.itemTitle,
                isDone: req.body.isDone

            })

            newItem.save((err, generatedItem) => {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(`Error Occured : ${err}`, 'Database', 10)
                    console.log(err)
                    let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Error Occured.', 500, null)
                    res.send(apiResponse)
                } else {
                    console.log('Success in new item creation, new generated item is-')
                    console.log(generatedItem)
                    result.child.push(newItem)
                    let listId = req.body.listId
                    result.save()
                    console.log("result after saving")
                    console.log(result)
                    ListModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "listId": req.body.listId, "items.itemId": req.params.itemId},
                    { "$set": { "items.$": result } }, {new:true}).exec((err, updatedlistresult) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('error in finding list for save')
                            console.log(err)
                        } else if(check.isEmpty(updatedlistresult)){
                            let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'updated result is empty', 500, null)
                            res.send(apiResponse)
                        }
                        else {
                            let apiResponse = response.generate(false, 'item saved', 200, updatedlistresult)
                            res.send(apiResponse)
                        }
                    })

                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

}
my schemas are-

```
  let listSchema = new Schema({
listId:{
    type:String,
    default:'',
    required: true,
    index:true
},
listTitle:{
    type:String
},
forUserId:{
    type:String,
    default: ''
},
items:[ItemSchema]
```

})
mongoose.model('List', listSchema);

// item schema

```
     itemSchema.add({
itemId:{
    type:String,
    default:'',
    index:true
},
itemTitle:{
    type:String
},
isDone:{
    type:Boolean,
    default:false
},
child:[itemSchema]
```

})

Comment: What are you getting in the console?

Comment: No error, sub item is generated,  but list is not updated,  when I'm requesting list detail from another API, this new item is not reflected in the parent list

Comment: Updated result is null

Comment: @MattKuhns I think the prob is here ListModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "listId": req.body.listId, "items.itemId": req.params.itemId},
                    { "$set": { "items.$": result } }